# How to make the title of UIBarButtonItem Logout after the first time button is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have login button at top bar with title login when user clicks on it it logins in app I want that after this same button show logout instead of login but it is not changing title.

`isCLikedLogins` is `NSString` first time it has NO values when click on login it gets YES.

Here is the code which I am using.

```
if ([appDelegate.isClickedLogin isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {
    signIn_BarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@" Logout " 
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                            target:self 
                            action:@selector(loginUser)];            
}
else {
    signIn_BarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@" Login " 
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                            target:self 
                            action:@selector(loginUser)];            
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =signIn_BarButton;
}
```

Comment: i think your appdelegete object is not initialized properly.

Comment: MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

.h

```
BOOL loginCheck;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    loginCheck = YES;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginPressed)
}
```

And in your `loginPressed` method:

```
- (void) loginPressed
{
    if (loginCheck)
    {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginPressed)
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginPressed)
    }
    loginCheck = !loginCheck
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try following code :

```
if ([appDelegate.isClickedLogin isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) 
{

  [signIn_BarButton setTitle:@"Logout"];           
}

else 
{

    signIn_BarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@" Login " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(loginUser)];            
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =signIn_BarButton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =signIn_BarButton;` out of the else statement, and ensure this code is called from either `viewDidLoad` (if you are creating a new instance of this view each time) or `viewDidAppear` (if you are reusing an existing instance).

I'd also recommend using a BOOL to track `isClickedLogin`rather than a string.